# Question on possesives

Tags: gramática

> Ellas leen nuestras cartas. =  They read our letters.

Why in the above sentence we cannot put

> nuestros

instead of

> nuestras

What is the grammatical rule that makes it nuestras?

Similarly in the other sentence:

> Nuestras gatas beben leche.

Why cannot it be nuestros in both the sentences above and in what case nuestros apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spanish, adjectives must agree in gender and number with the noun they modify.

> Es**os** gatos blanc**os**  (masculine, plural)
>
> Es**a** gata blanc**a** (feminine, singular)

However, gender agreement is not always need in the possessive and numbers, since usually no male / female distinction, **except in nuestro/nuestra**, which does make the distinction.

Then, possessive adjectives list is:

- Mi (mi gato, mi gata) [my]
- Mis (mis gatos, mis gatas) [my]
- Tu (tu gato, tu gata) [your (of @AaKASH)]
- Tus (tus gatos, tus gatas) [your (of @AaKASH)]
- Su (su gato, su gata) [his, her, its, your (of @AaKASH and friends), their]
- Sus (sus gatos, sus gatas) [his, her, its, your (of @AaKASH and friends), their]
- Nuestro (nuestro gato) [our]
- Nuestra (nuestra gata) [our]
- Nuestros (nuestros gatos) [our]
- Nuestras (nuestras gatas) [our]

Also considers that plural male (mis gatos, tus gatos, sus gatos, nuestros gatos) can be used to refer only to males or couples or groups of male and female cats.

In Spain, the male / female difference also exists in the second person (vuestro, vuestra, vuestros, vuestras). In Latin America this adjective does not exist and instead form *su  - sus* is repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Nuestras is "femenine" and Nuestros is "masculine". So in

> Ellas leen nuestras cartas.

Cartas is femenine so should nuestras

But in

> Nuestras gatas beben leche.

gatas means female cats, but if you want male cats would be

> Nuestros gatos beben leche.

Note that it changes the gender of the cats too.